Does Emacs support stripping comments in CLI mode?
While researching how to remove C and C++ style comments from a file, I stumbled on the following two comments by Alan Mackenzie from almost 20 years ago:

I can assure you, as half of the Emacs CC Mode team (which includes full
support for AWK, by the way ;-), that C Comments can be recognised
without parsing the language beyond the level of comments and strings. C
comments can be fully recognised by regular expressions (because,
containing no unbounded nesting, they are finite-state mechanical),
though those regexps are considerably more involved than one might at
first expect.
The proof of the pudding is in the eating - Load a file.c into Emacs, and
its comments get correctly "fontified" (syntax highlighted), no matter
how cleverly you attempt to confuse it. Emacs does not contain a C
compiler.


But you'd probably
be better off following the suggestion of using the C preprocessor to
eliminate the comments. Or maybe you could use Emacs, searching for
blocks of text fontified with font-lock-comment-face, and deleting these.

and I, being a beginner Emacs user, have the same question as Ed Morton:

Also, the main point here is to strip C comments, so let us know if
emacs can do that with a flag and without going into a GUI editting
mode. If so, and I knew where to get the tool, I'd probably use that one
tool rather than the chain of sed/gcc commands I posted elsethread.

Currently, I'm borrowing a very complex sed script to do the job, but still it fails in some very edge cases. I dismissed the C preprocessor method because doing that in a reasonably side effect free way requires GCC with support for some options that are only available in select platforms. Also, I later found out that the files I want to remove comments from also support Python style comments, and there is no way I'm modifying that IQ-200 sed script, but it seems rather easy to do in Emacs.
My question is, is there a way to strip comments of the forms /*comment*/, //comment and #comment using only the command-line interface through a pipeline of Emacs scripts and Unix utilities?

What is the exact specification for the comments? Do the //-style and #-style comments end at the end of the line? Are the delimiters limited to column 1 or can they start in the middle of a line? What happens if you have a //'  or a #inside a/* ... */` comment? We could make up our own rules, but it would be better if you specified them exactly.

@NickD The specification is described in https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/modules/libpref/parser/src/lib.rs, Firefox's prefs parser, but that is mildly relevant as this question could be applicable to more than an ad-hoc config format.

You should add your comment to your question, although the description in the link is as incomplete as the description in your question. You (and they) really need to specify exactly what the syntax is. Only then can somebody hope to write a correct program - otherwise you will always be saying "it fails in some very edge cases."

The sed program admits that it has been "bugfixed to some extent" (so it's still buggy), and I remember it has a different output than cpp when an unterminated multiline string is encountered (I can add the test case to the question later when I find it; emacs' syntax highlighting agrees with cpp's output so it's definitely more robust than the sed script). The /* ... */ style comments are block comments while // and # are line comments, just like in C and Python. I don't know how to specify them in a formal grammar, nor do I think that's useful.

The main thing I want to know is if emacs can do comment removal from the CLI natively without resorting to RPA or GUI automation.

What does "natively" mean? No configuration allowed? No extra Lisp code allowed? That's an ambiguous requirement as well. Emacs can do what sed can do (albeit more expensively), but it probably will require some configuration - maybe writing some functions and arranging for Emacs to call them during the processing. But it's hard to be precise since the question is not precise enough.

[Not an answer. I just wanted to give a couple of examples that are ambiguous and need to be nailed down more precisely, before a "correct" program can be written; comments are not suitable for that.]
Consider a file containing this text:
Some text

// some comment # containing an octothorpe /* and what looks like a C-style
* comment that extends across multiple lines
*/

/* A C-style comment that extends
across multiple lines and
# contains an octothorpe on the last line of the comment */

Some more text

/* A C-style comment */

What should the output of the program be when given this input? Note that this has nothing to do with Emacs: you would have to specify the output before any program (Emacs, sed, bash , Rust, Go, whatever) can be written. And there might be more ambiguities that need to be specified. That's what I mean by "exact": whether you use a formal grammar, or a description in English I don't much care, as long as you cover all the cases.

Or some doxigen comments starting with ///...
